# How to make a right skewed Weibull distribution on Python

Tags: python, weibull

[This is my left skewed weibull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdIwB.jpg) distribution for a battery state of charge distribution. Can you help me make it right skewed? Thanks!

```
def create_soc_distribution(self) -> np.array:
        
        multiplier = 25
        np.random.seed(4)

        socs = np.zeros((1000, 1))
        for i in range(socs.shape[0]):
            for j in range(socs.shape[1]):
                socs[i,j] = round(5 + np.random.weibull(1.5) * multiplier)
        return socs
```

Comment: You need to provide some more details on what you have tried. The code above is not replicable as is. Is it a plot you want? make sure to show your research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the parameter you are passing to the Weibull distribution (1.5) and it's [behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), it is already right-skewed. A sample from 1000 draws of `np.random.weibull(1.5,1000)` plotted as histogram shows a right-skewed distribution. You can check the example on numpy's [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.weibull.html):

[image]

Where as a using a parameter larger than 5, will prove left-skewedness:

[image: d]

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer but when i run my code i get a left skewed one. Could you run this code on your side? : import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
multiplier = 25
np.random.seed(4)
socs = np.zeros((1000, 1))
x = np.arange(1, 100.) / 50.
for i in range(socs.shape[0]):
    for j in range(socs.shape[1]):
        socs[i, j] = round(5 + np.random.weibull(1.5) * multiplier)
        plt.plot(socs)
        plt.show()